# How to filter Facebook custom audience GET request by data_source type and subtype via filtering parameter

Tags: c#, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-custom-audience

I am trying to filter Facebook custom audience that we get via this endpoint:

```
var url = $"{advertiserId}/customaudiences?limit={limit}&fields=name" 
                  + "&filtering=[{'field':'subtype','operator':'EQUAL', 'value':'CUSTOM'}]";
```

The above call works and returns the users custom audience. However, I need to additionally filter custom audiences by data_source.type and data-source.subtype, i.e.

```
filtering=[...{'field':'data_source.type','operator':'EQUAL', 'value':'FILE_IMPORTED'}]";
```

I have read through the documentation and cannot see where I am going wrong.

I get an

> Invalid parameter

error when trying to filter by data_source.type

Here is the documentation I've looked at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/customaudiences/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/#parameters-2

Comment: Have you solved this? I am facing the same issue...

Comment: @VitorDurante Yes I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding data_souce to my request URL and the filtering on data_source using a list I created and stored in the config:

```
public FacebookEntitiesResult<FacebookAudience> GetFacebookAudiences(string advertiserId, string token, int? limit, PagingCursors cursors)
    {
        if (!limit.HasValue)
            limit = ConfigValues.FacebookGraphResultLimit;

        var url = $"{advertiserId}/customaudiences?limit={limit}&fields=name,data_source"
                  + "&filtering=[{'field':'subtype','operator':'EQUAL', 'value':'CUSTOM'}]";

        var customAudienceTypes = Instance.Of<IConfigHelper>().GetStringArrayOfAppSettings(ConfigKeys.Extensions.FacebookAudienceUnsupportedTypeArray, ",");

        var customAudiences = GetResult<FacebookEntitiesResult<FacebookAudience>>(url, token, cursors);
        customAudiences.Data = customAudiences.Data.Where(a => !customAudienceTypes.Contains(a.Data_Source.Type)).ToArray();

        return customAudiences;
    }
```

Config:

```
<key name="FacebookAudienceUnsupportedTypeArray" defaultValue="THIRD_PARTY_IMPORTED"></key>
```